# after clicking on button only first part of JS script is used, after second click none works

Tags: javascript

Hey this is my function

```
function open() {
            
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "20%";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
function close() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function Test() {
var item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft ="";
if (item = "0%")
{
    w3_open()
    item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%";
} else if (item = "20%")
{
    w3_close()
}
```

}

First part works perfectly, but after second click none happens..

Idk whats wrong, can someone some suggestions?

///UPDATE

After clicking this:

```
<button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="Test()">&#9776;</button>
```

I can open sidebar, but after clicking again i cannot close it. :/

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click (click what?) the second time? Please provide full (self-sufficient) example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nikolay done, i forget to show my button

Comment: in your `if`-statement you are making an assignment and not a comparison. It should be if( item == "0%").

Comment: @zelite i changed it but not working :/

Comment: did you remove the  =""; from first line of the Test() function yet? See my answer below.

Comment: @pzutils yes i changed and nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues going here, including assigning values when they should be performing comparisons (noted in several comments and other answers).

Even if the syntax is fixed, I suspect the function will never work because the `marginLeft` value has never been set to begin with, which means neither `open()` nor `close()` will ever be invoked since they are only invoked if a specific value is found.

Everything can be simplified in the `Test()` method with a single evaluation. Here's an updated version:

```js
function open() {
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%"
   document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "20%"
   document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block"
   document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block"
}

function close() {
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%"
   document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none"
   document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block"
}

function Test() {
   var item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft

   // simplified condition
   if (item == "20%") close()
   else open()
}
```

Comment: This is the answer for my question! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

`item` will never equal `"0%"` because you're specifically setting it to `""` here:

```
var item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft ="";
```

This is why it's always going to the else statement. Change that line that line to `var item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft`

Also just noticed your if else statement is messed up - you need to use `==` instead of `=`. Your if statement is currently assigning `item = "0%"` but you want it to evaluate if `item == "0%"` instead. So this is actually another reason why it's always opening - because assigning a value inside an if statement will basically always evaluate to true. Try fixing these issues and let me know if the code works

One more note - `w3_open()` and `w3_close()` should just be `open()` and `close()`

Comment: Hello, this is not working. Just opening and not closing :/...

Comment: let me see your revised code - it's working for me

Comment: main also needs to have a default existing value for margin-left as mentioned in anurag-dhamala's answer below

Comment: this is not working!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your default marginLeft of element wtih id "main" to 0% in stylesheet. Then change your functions as below:

```
function open() {
        
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "20%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    }
function close() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
}

function Test() {
    var item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft;
    if (item == "0%"){
        open()
    } else if (item == "20%"){    
         close()
       }
}
```

Comment: the if else statements are still messed up here - you need to be evaluating item == "0%" rather than assigning item = "0%"

Comment: Oops ! Just copy pasted the answer from question . And forgot to modify it . My bad

Comment: @anurag-dhamala this is not working

Comment: The answer is edited. Check it. Forgot to change the function names. You have different names while defining  and calling.

Comment: @anurag-dhamala not working :O

Answer (score -1):

I hope it works

If it didn't .plz let me know

First why u write this.as they're same in both open and close function?

```
Id("openNav").style.display='inline-block';
```

In

```
function close() and open()
```

try this with above note.

```
function open() { 

document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%"; 

  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "20%";  
 
document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block"; 

 document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'inline-block'; } 
 function close() { 

 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0"; 

 document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0 !important"; 

 document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block"; } 
function Test() { 
var item=document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft ;
 if (item == "0") { 
 w3_open() item = document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft ;
} else if (item == "20%") { w3_close() }
```

Comment: this does not even open this..

Comment: Sorry.check now

Comment: I am with mobile.can u send me a screen shot or a pic.

Comment: the if else statement is still messed up - you should be evaluating item == "0%" not assigning item = "0%"

Comment: I just copy the code. Something went wrong while submitting.check it out

Comment: Plz don't vote negative first check out your issue

Comment: dont work, idk why.. if i will know i will not ask.

Comment: Can u share your code and a pic in somewhere to see what u have done so that I could help u

Comment: Yes, we can go to the chat. Tell me if it is possible

Comment: Let's do it.I'm on